# esp32 cam cannot upload please help me asap god will help you too

Tags: flash, arduino

example file i used

CameraWebServer.ino

Arduino: 1.8.10 (Windows 10), Board: "ESP32 Wrover Module, Huge APP (3MB No OTA/1MB SPIFFS), QIO, 80MHz, 921600

esptool.py v2.6
Serial port COM6
Connecting....
Chip is ESP32D0WDQ6 (revision 1)
Features: WiFi, BT, Dual Core, 240MHz, VRef calibration in efuse, Coding Scheme None
MAC: 24:6f:28:2a:44:8c
Uploading stub...
Running stub...
Stub running...
Changing baud rate to 921600
Changed.
Configuring flash size...
Auto-detected Flash size: 4MB
Compressed 8192 bytes to 47...

Writing at 0x0000e000... (100 %)
Wrote 8192 bytes (47 compressed) at 0x0000e000 in 0.0 seconds (effective 4096.1 kbit/s)...

A fatal error occurred: Timed out waiting for packet header
A fatal error occurred: Timed out waiting for packet header

Comment: Please clarify the issue with more details about your setup and what exactly you're trying to accomplish here. IMO this question is too vague. Also, it would be better to format command line output using markup instead of just typing it into the questions as a paragraph.

Comment: i am trying to upload my a code on esp32s cam. it connects at first but then it shows this error and when i check if it is connected properly or not by trying clicking reset button while serial monitor is on it shows ready for download thanks for turning up your head for help,soory for my bad english                                      regards,                                                                                                                                    innovative

Comment: Have you tried holding down the "BOOT" button the entire time while you are flashing?